# How to set up host redirection in a forward proxy in apache?

Tags: apache-2.4, proxy, redirect

I have set up an apache proxy on my dev computer, so that I can redirect all requests to `prod.example.com` to `staging.example.com`, for reasons that are outside of the scope of this question.   The proxy is working correctly, but I can't make the redirection to work.

Here is my `forward_proxy.conf` file, from `/etc/apache/sites-enabled`:

```
<VirtualHost *:9999>

ProxyRequests On
ProxyVia On

<Proxy *>
  Require ip 192.168
  Redirect permanent prod.example.com/ staging.example.com/
</Proxy>


ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error_forward_proxy.log
CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access_forward_proxy.log combined

</VirtualHost>
```

I have tried many variations of the `Redirect` line, but it either fail completely (proxy not working), or the redirection is ignored. What's the correct syntax, or correct way to achieve this?

Comment: I suggest you read [the documentation again](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/remapping.html). And the [Reverse Proxy Guide](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/howto/reverse_proxy.html) as well, because right now you are not proxying anything.

Comment: That's a forward proxy I'm looking for, not a reverse one. I'm seeing in logs that my requests indeed go through this, so I'd say it is proxying correctly. Thx for the RTFM though, just what I was looking for.

Comment: My bad. Does that mean you want to redirect clients that are requesting prod.example.com via your proxy to staging.example.com?

Comment: yes, exactly. And leave all other requests untouched (pass-thhrough).

Comment: Hm, that's an interesting problem. Off hand I don't see any way to do that. I might be able to test some things later, but maybe someone else has already experience with this.